# jQuery.data() is not working in IE10. Any other way to implement?

Tags: jquery, cross-browser, internet-explorer-10

I have a text area, and on any change I need to change other label with the new value and some other value I'm getting from the server at page load.

I'm creating a calculation object and attaching it to the textarea by using the [jQuery data method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/).

When the value changed in the textarea I retrieve the calc object, load it with the new value and update accordingly.

Everything works great on all browsers except from IE10.

In IE10 there is an error when the browser loads the JS: `SCRIPT3: Member not found` and then when trying to retrieve the objects, it fails.

I read in the jQuery file itself that it is related to the problem of IE with get/setAttribute.

I also found [this documented bug](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12577).

Is there other way to attach storage to a DOM element?

What are my options here?

**Edit**: I'm adding some of my code:

Attaching the object to the element:

```
myField = $('#url-example');

fullUrl = FullUrl("http://www.example.com/category/article?", something);

myField.data("fullUrl", fullUrl);
```

Retrieving:

```
tiedFullUrl = $('#url-example').data('fullUrl');

tiedFullUrl.setUrl(url);

doSomethingWithTheObject(tiedFullUrl);
```

---

**I'm adding more info:**

I'm getting the same error as [this guy](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/bug-in-ie-10).

---

**

### More info:

**

I created a workaround:

--from jquery.1.7.1.js, line 2700:

```
if (!$.browser.msie || $.browser.version < 7) { //my hack
  return ( ret.nodeValue = value + "" );
}
```

Comment: What does the *"documented bug"* have to do with this? are you using IE in compatibility mode? Can you please provide some code?

Comment: Can you show the code that you're using that is throwing the error? I'm having a hard time believing that `$.data()` is completely broken in IE10.

Comment: 1. I added some of my code. 2. in the discussion around the bug, many others claim that it is happened to them with IE10 not in compatibility view.

Comment: What does FullUrl() return? And it's unclear to me, does the browser throw the error when you're setting the value or getting the value?

Comment: 1. it is a ctor that returns a new object. 2. the "method not found" is thrown when the page loads. the error about not founding a method of the object (because it is undefined) is thrown when I'm trying to retrieve and use.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `$('#selector').data('foo')`, have you considered using `$('#selector').attr('data-foo')`?

Comment: There is something about .data() that causes some issues somewhere but I forgot exactly what it was. This answer should solve your problem

Comment: What exactly are you loading into the data attribute?

Comment: @JordanBrown - I'm trying to store an object in it.

Answer (score 0):

The key has to be in small caps. That's how I get it working in IE10.

Replace

`myField.data("fullUrl", fullUrl);` with
`myField.data("fullurl", fullUrl);`

and

`tiedFullUrl = $('#url-example').data('fullUrl');` with
`tiedFullUrl =$('#url-example').data('fullurl');`